# Why separate entry points for left-handed and right-handed matrices instead of a handedness flag or conversion function?

Tags: c++, math, graphics, directx, directx-11

The [DirectX Math](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee415594(v=vs.85).aspx) API for matrix calculation contains separate functions for generating left handed vs. right handed matrices (e.g. `XMMatrixLookAtLH` vs. `XMMatrixLootAtRH` alongside `XMMatrixPerspectiveLH` vs. `XMMatrixPerspectiveRH`).

I don't exactly understand the full difference between the two coordinate systems (especially as they apply to traditional DirectX and OpenGL) but why is the API structured like this, as opposed to combining the entry points and providing, say, an `enum` indicating handedness or an extra generic function that converts a matrix intended for a right handed system to a left handed one (or vice versa)? Is it simply that both operations need to be fast (i.e. you could provide those options, but they would be too slow for any practical purposes and thus not worth supporting) or is there something fundamental about these matrix functions that requires the LH and RH variations to be entirely separate endpoints?

**EDIT:** To clarify: While I do appreciate answers expounding on why the API design decisions were made, my primary curiosity is whether a parameterization or after-the-fact conversion function *can* be implemented correctly or efficiently when you consider the math and the implementation (i.e. if the two halves can't really share code, that would be inefficient).

Answer (score 4):

The [DirectXMath](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMath) project has a long history to it. I started working on it back in 2008 when it was "xboxmath" for the Xbox 360 focused on VMX128 with no SSE/SSE2 optimizations. Much of the initial API surface area has been preserved since then as I've tried to maintain support for existing clients as I moved from xboxmath to xnamath then xnamath to DirectXMath, including this "LH" vs. "RH" as two distinct functions.

There is a practical reason for this design: a single application is only going to use one or the other, not both. Having a potential run-time check of a parameter to pick something that is fixed and known is not that useful.

> Another practical reason is to minimize branching in the code. Most of the DirectXMath functions are straight-line code that avoids all branching, using element selects instead. This was originally motivated by the fact that the Xbox 360 was an extremely fast in-order processor, but didn't have a particularly advanced branch predictor.

Generally the choice of viewing coordinate system is a matter of historical comfort: OpenGL has long preferred column-major, right-handed viewing systems. DirectX has historically used row-major, left-handed viewing coordinates. XNA Game Studio choose to go with row-major, right-handed viewing coordinates.

With the modern programmable GPU pipeline, there is actually no requirement to use one or the other as long as you are consistent: the DirectX API can support either LH or RH. Most DirectX samples including anything written using [DXUT](https://github.com/Microsoft/DXUT) uses left-handed viewing coordinates. Most Windows Store samples and .NET-based systems generally stick with the XNA Game Studio convention.

Because of all this, DirectXMath supports row-major matrices and leave it up to the developer to use Right-Handed vs. Left-Handed. The [SimpleMath](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/SimpleMath) wrapper for DirectXMath is intended to be natural to those coming from C#'s XNA Game Studio math library, so it assumes right-handed.

In response to @galpo1n: "DirectXMath is quite ancient now too, not a good example of C++, it is good enough for what it does, but most project would rewrite their math library."

xboxmath's tradition is to use C callable functions because in the early days of Xbox 360 there were still plenty of developers who preferred C over C++. That has become far less important over time as C++ compilers have matured and developer tastes have changed. In the transition from XNAMath to DirectXMath, I made the library C++ only (i.e. no C) and took advantage of things like `stdint.h`, C++ namespaces, and I made use of templates and specializations to improve the implementation of permutes and shuffle operations for the SSE/SSE2 instruction set.

The C++ language use of DirectXMath has also tracked the Visual C++ compiler support. DirectXMath 3.08 uses `=default`, and the upcoming 3.09 release uses `constexpr`. At it's core, it remains a basically C interface by design. Really the best way to think of it is that each DirectXMath function is a 'meta-intrinsic'. They are all inline, and really you want the compiler to stitch a bunch of them together into one codepath for maximum efficiency. While more recent compilers have gotten better at optimizing C++ code patterns, even the old ones (think Visual C++ .NET 2002 era) did pretty well with C code.

> The original API implemented VXM128 and "no-intrinsics". XNAMath implemented VMX128, no-intrinsics, and SSE/SSE2 for x86 & x64. DirectXMath no longer supports VXM128, but added ARM-NEON and I've since added optional codepaths for SSE3, SSE4.1, AVX, and AVX2. As such, this C-style API has proven to map well to the SIMD intrinsics operations across a variety of processor families.

SimpleMath is where I decided to put C++ type conversion behaviors to hide the verbosity around loading & storing data. This is less efficient as the programmer may not realize that they are actually doing something expensive, which is why I kept it out of the base library. If you avoid SimpleMath and stick with DirectXMath, then you will be writing more verbose code but in return you know when you are doing something that's potentially performance impacting where with C++ implicit conversions and constructors you can end up spilling to memory through temporaries when you didn't expect to. If I had put this in the base library, performance-sensitive programmers couldn't easily opt-out. It's all a matter of trade-offs.

**UPDATE:** If you really need a parameterized version, you could do something simple and let the compiler take care of optimizing it:

```
inline XMMATRIX XM_CALLCONV XMMatrixPerspectiveFov(float FovAngleY, float AspectRatio, float NearZ, float FarZ, bool rhcoords )
{
    if (rhcoords)
    {
        return XMMatrixPerspectiveFovRH(FovAngleY, AspectRatio, NearZ, FarZ);
    }
    else
    {
        return XMMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(FovAngleY, AspectRatio, NearZ, FarZ);
    }
}
```

The library is all inline, so you basically have the source. Each case is a little different, so you can optimize each parameterized version individually. Some of the functions have full expansions of codepaths, some just have one. In most cases it just comes down to a negative on the Z.

Comment: Thank you, that certainly makes sense - since only one set of functions is called in most situations, only one set will get loaded and things will go fast. To clarify, however, is it true that a flag-based or end-transformation-based solution *could* feasibly have been done?

Comment: It could be parameterized, but it's not clear when you'd use it.

Comment: The issue with SIMD emphasis is that it is done for wrong reason at wrong places. On PPC, there was a 15cycles cost for the first instruction, and with SIMD only on low math function, you load hit store all over the place with code going back and forth to scalar. SIMD Strength is not to optimize a function like `vec4::operator+` or `TestOneSphereAgainstFrustum`, but `TestManySphereAgainstFrustum`, And you may need SOA fashion instead of AOS for best result. How many projection matrix do you compute every frame ? at worst a dozen ? Saving 12 if is not where you should focus your attention.

Comment: Which is why the DirectXMath functions are written to be easy for the compiler to composite into a larger codepath that remains SIMD without going back & forth with scalar.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn How can you have right handed vectors & matrices in DirectXMath. As far as I know `XMVECTOR` `XMMATRIX` are left handed only. Are there right handed versions? I feel like I'm missing something..

Comment: The DirectXMath library is always using "row-major matrices, row vectors, and pre-multiplication". You can use either right-handed -or- left-handed viewing coordinates. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dxmath/pg-xnamath-getting-started#matrix-convention). For column-major matrices such as those typically needed by default HLSL, use ``XMMatrixTranspose``. See [HLSL Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-per-component-math).

Answer (score 0):

This is quite opinion based to design an API. In an engine, the time you spend computing a matrix with an effective difference based on the handiness is negligible. They could have use a set of flags to drive instead of name and code duplication without any real major issue.

`DirectXMath` is quite ancient now too, not a good example of C++, it is good enough for what it does, but most project would rewrite their math library.

With modern GPU and shaders, the handiness is a pure fashion choice, as long as your pipeline is consistant, or perform conversion when required, from the modeling tool to the render engine. It is worth to note that in addition to handiness, you often have to deal with a Y or Z up convention.

The easy way to understand handiness is to form a frame with your finger ( thumb is X, index is Y, middle is Z ). If you do that with both your hands and try to align two fingers, the difference is obvious, the third axis is inverted. That's all :)